# I am trying to update data but getting error using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update data by foreign key but unfortunately I am getting error please help me how can I solved this issue thanks.

Please check error.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::Save does not exist.

**controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, Variation $variation)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => "required|max:191|unique:App\Variation,name,{$variation->id}",
        'variation_details' => 'required'
    ]);

    $variation->name = $request->name;
    $variation->save();
    
    $input = $request->except('_token');
    
    $variationDetails = VariationDetails::where('variation_id', $variation->id)
        ->get();
    // return $variationDetails;
    
    if ($request->variation_details) {
        foreach ($request->variation_details   as  $value) {
            $variationDetails->variation_id = $variation->id;
            $variationDetails->name = $value;
            $variationDetails->Save();
        }
    }
    
    // form helpers.php
    logAction($request);
    
    return redirect()->route('variation');
}
```

**return $request->all()**

```
{
"_token": "90jUMkvPgYOz64iT4zma1D2Ydkfp2sDodZ2c9Sno",
"_method": "put",
"name": "Storagefgfdgfdgdfg",
"variation_details": [
"32gb",
"16gb",
"32gb",
"32gb",
"32gb",
"32gb",
"32gb",
"32gb"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$variationDetails = VariationDetails::where('variation_id', $variation->id)->get();`

To

`$variationDetails = VariationDetails::where('variation_id', $variation->id)->first();`

Comment: please can you check return request->all() on top

Comment: `request->all()` is fine.

Comment: sir error resolved but not i am trying to  update any data not updating

Comment: you are updating or inserting data.

Comment: updating record

Comment: in this case, you need to remove `VariationDetails` record and insert a new record based on `variation_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Use first() instead of get() like below:

```
$variationDetails = VariationDetails::where('variation_id', $variation->id)->first();
```

Because when you are using get after where clause it will return a collection of model instead of a model object

Answer (score 0):

Your code for updating data is not looking proper.

ideally it should be.

```
$var = VariationDetails::where('variation_id', $variation->id);

$var->name = $request->name;
$var->save();
```

Hope this will be useful.